# Unable to retrieve the current windows username in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms

I'm afraid that this may be a double post, but I've been pulling hair out for hours trying to solve this one - hope someone can clarify what I'm doing wrong.

I'm implementing a webforms application on an intranet, and I want to use windows authentication. I have not built the website myself, so maybe it's something behind the scenes that makes this confusing.

- I've enabled windows authentication in the IIS website
- I've disabled anonymous authentication in IIS
- I've set the web.config file to use windows authentication
- I've set the authorization in web config to deny anonymous users

When I navigate to a page, the website responds with a redirect response header, and redirects to /account/login, and this seems to go around in circles, because after about 20 redirects I finally get a querystring too long error:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://mysite/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin
%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAcc
ount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FLo
gin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%2
52525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FAccount%25252525252FLogi
n%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FAccount%2525252
525252FLogin%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525253D%252525252525252
FAccount%252525252525252FLogin%252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525253
D%25252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525253
FReturnUrl%25252525252525253D%2525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252
52525252FLogin%2525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525253D%252
525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525
2525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252553D%25252525252525252525252FAccou
nt%25252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252252525253FReturnUrl%252
52525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252
525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525
25252525253D%252525252525252525252525252Flogin
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 11 Sep 2016 00:08:19 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Could someone help me point to a solution where I can discover what's going on?

Comment: create a aspx page and check it's picking up the id and auth type from iis. Sounds like your app is using forms authentication, is it MVC / WebApi, does it have an app.config, an appstart folder, a WebApiConfig you'll probably find the auth scheme in one of those

Comment: Thanks @saj - my unfamiliaity with the `app_start/startup.auth` file was what confused me in my debugging. Thanks for pointing it out. Problem solved after commenting out the `.LoginPath` section of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to suggest that your `Form Authentication` is still enabled. You might want to go through your web.config again and check the configurations are indeed proper and correct.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
         <authorization>
             <deny users="?"/>
          </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Also it's worth checking any sub-level web.config (if applicable in your case) and its configurations.

You can refer to following links for more details.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/Recipe_3A00_-Enabling-Windows-Authentication-within-an-Intranet-ASP.NET-Web-application

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323176